# Convert a 2x3 df to vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a df like:

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~names, ~values,
    "aa",       1,
    "bb",       2,
    "cc",       3
  )
```

I want it to transform into a vector as follows:

```
vector <- c(`aa` = 1, `bb` = 2, `cc` = 3)
```

how to perform this operation in the `tidyverse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `deframe`

```
library(tibble)
v1 <- deframe(tbl1)
v1
#  aa bb cc 
#  1  2  3 


identical(v1, vector)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or using `base R` with `setNames`

```
setNames(tbl1$values, tbl1$names)
```

#### data

```
tbl1 <- tibble::tribble(
 ~names, ~values,
  "aa",       1,
  "bb",       2,
  "cc",       3
   )
```